# Append is overwriting existing data in list of classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, append, inner-classes

I'm making a sudoku solving program in Python.

I have a **class**, an **inner class**, a **list**, *constructors* and a *function* that would make the **list** of **Row** objects.

```
    class Table:

       rows = []

       def __init__(self):
          initRows()

       class Row:

          numbers = []

          def __init__(self):
             "stuff that stores a list of integers in **numbers** list"

       def initRows(self, numbers):
          for i in range(9):
             temp_row = self.Row(i, numbers)
             self.rows.append(temp_row)
```

The program goes like this:

1. When a **Table** object is created it automatically tries to make a 9 length list of **Row** objects with the *initRows()* function.
2. In the *initRows()* function we just create a temporary object of class **Row** and instantly *append()* it to the *rows* list.
3. When we create a **Row** object it just stores the given numbers for the given row of the sudoku table.
4. If I *print()* the *numbers* list of each temporary **Row** object after it is created then it gives the correct values.

```
[0, 0, 0, 7, 4, 0, 0, 0, 6]
[4, 0, 6, 8, 0, 0, 5, 0, 7]
[7, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 4]
[0, 3, 0, 9, 8, 4, 7, 0, 0]
[8, 2, 0, 6, 1, 3, 4, 0, 9]
[0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0]
[0, 6, 2, 3, 7, 0, 0, 0, 5]
[0, 0, 5, 4, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 7, 0, 0, 6, 1, 2, 0, 8]
```

5. But when I try to *print()* the values of each **Row** object after the *for loop* loops once or more or after the initialization is finished then the list is filled with only the last **Row** object

```
[0, 7, 0, 0, 6, 1, 2, 0, 8]
[0, 7, 0, 0, 6, 1, 2, 0, 8]
[0, 7, 0, 0, 6, 1, 2, 0, 8]
[0, 7, 0, 0, 6, 1, 2, 0, 8]
[0, 7, 0, 0, 6, 1, 2, 0, 8]
[0, 7, 0, 0, 6, 1, 2, 0, 8]
[0, 7, 0, 0, 6, 1, 2, 0, 8]
[0, 7, 0, 0, 6, 1, 2, 0, 8]
[0, 7, 0, 0, 6, 1, 2, 0, 8]
[0, 7, 0, 0, 6, 1, 2, 0, 8]
```

I was searching on the internet for **hours** and found that people have issues with the *append()* function of the list class but nothing helped.

So my question is: How could I make this work?

*(If any other information/part of code is needed: ask away!)*

Comment: You are probably adding a reference to the same “numbers” list to each row, which is why they all end up being the same in the end. Try something like numbers.copy() see if it makes any difference

Comment: @NewPythonUser That's not the issue. Their value is different as I mentioned in the 4th point. They are the correct value before the for loop finishes 1 iteration. But after the for loop jumps to the next iteration, the self.rows.append() function overwrites ALL of the other entries in the list, as I mentioned in the 5th point.
(Btw, I tried it and didn't make any difference)

Comment: Then it’s hard to tell from the example you gave. But since the values are the same for all rows it is most likely they all point to the same list (by reference)

Comment: Another suggestion. Change the class attributes to instance attributes. Especially the ‘numbers’ attribute under the Row class. See more info here: https://dzone.com/articles/python-class-attributes-vs-instance-attributes

Comment: @NewPythonUser When I'm printing the values it's jsut simply:
for i in range(9):
   print(self.rows[i].numbers)

Comment: I think I'm going to eat my pants because it worked.... Changing from class attribute to instance attribute. Holy molly

Comment: It is most probably due to the fact I only started Python 3 days ago.

Comment: Don't use a nested class, it provides no advantage and is simply unidiomatic

Answer (score 1):

It turns out in the **Row** class the ***numbers*** list was a *class* attribute (means it's shared across all objects of the **Row** class) rather than an *instance* attribute.